# Proper way to assess Role in Authorization as User.IsInRole() always returns false

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

A lot has been asked around the User.IsInRole, but I cannot find the right answer.

I need to validate a certain role, by using an AuthorizationHandler (through a authorizationrequirement)

I have a ASP.NET Core 2.1 project, whith Individual User Accounts. I have seeded the database and added the user to a (one role) role using `userManager.AddToRoleAsync` and, yes, the database shows the users, the roles and connection between them.

I have created a CandidateViewHandler that controls the authorization for a View-Contorller. IT looks as follows

```
public class CandidateViewHandler : AuthorizationHandler<ViewCandidateRequirement, Candidate>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, ViewCandidateRequirement requirement, Candidate resource)
    {
        if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            if (resource.Email == context.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name).Value)
            {
                context.Succeed(requirement);
            }
            else
            {
                bool IsAdmin = context.User.IsInRole("Administrator");
                bool IsSearch = context.User.IsInRole("Searcher");                    
                if (IsAdmin == true || IsSearch == true)
                {
                    context.Succeed(requirement);
                }
            }
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

However, `IsAdmin` and `IsSearch` always return `false`. Even when testing it in the controller, the results remain the same. Should I use `Claims` in 2.1? And if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the discussion, mentioned by Charles de M., IMO actually shows is that roles are in fact an unnecessary addition to identity. Seems to me that for the future it would be better to remove the *AspNetRoles* table (or at least not to use it anymore) and use roles as claims directly, instead of having identity to add the roles as claims.

Add your *role type claims* to the *AspNetUserClaims* table. The default [role claim type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.claims.claimtypes_members.aspx) is `http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role`. Any claim of that type should automatically be mapped as role so it can be used with *IsInRole*.

You can also use custom mapping in the client:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                RoleClaimType = "role",
                NameClaimType = "name",
            };
    });
```

A side note, you may consider to not use roles at all any more, as asp.net core has many, more advanced features which you can use for authorization.

Comment: Hi Ruard, thanks for your comment. I will most certainly try it out. I find the "Claims"-concept still quite confusing and the documentation even more. Suppose I have a custom property (e.g. "TenantId") inside my ApplicationUser, can I reference it directly as a claim, or should I first add it as a ClaimsType?.

Comment: Simply put, a claim is a key/value pair. You can use it for any property, even roles. As long as the 'key' (claim type) is unique for its use (collections are allowed: role=admin, role=manager). So it's fine to add a claim `tenantid=42`, but `http://mycompany.com/tenantid` is more distinctive. Identity will add the claims automatically to the user, while for ApplicationUser properties you'll have to write code to add these properties as claims. You may as well skip that step and add the properties directly to the claims table. And as a bonus, you don't have to extend the IdentityUser any more.

Answer (score 0):

Apparantly ASP.NET CORE 2.1 has problems dealing with roles: https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1813, as is explained in that Thread. The questions still remains on how to replace Roles with Claims though.

The workaround is to fallback to an older configuration in the `startup` file:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultUI()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
```

(So remove `AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>.AddRole<ApplicationRole>` and replace with `AddIdentity<AppplicationRole, ApplicationUser>`. Now everything works fine.

Comment: I have a custom user and I can't get IsInRole to do anything but return true. I have services.AddIdentity<MyCustomUser, IdentityRole>

Comment: I would need to look at your code. I suggest to post it as a question and not as a comment in that case. More persons -and far better programmers- can then help you. and take a look at the link I included https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1813.